# Align text to an input field in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Im not quite sure on how I can place the paragraph 2 at the bottom of the div right next to the input field. I employed some css from a post from here but it does not work (at least in my case)

```
        <div className = 'group'>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input 
            name = "password"
            type = "password" 
            value = {this.state.password} 
            onChange = {this.handleChange} 
            />
            <p>{this.state.passwordError}</p>
            <p className = 'group' >{this.state.passwordError2}</p>
        </div><br></br>
```

CSS

```
 .group {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
.infotext {
 display: inline-block;
  }
```

[image: Here is a picture of what it looks like right now]
[image: And how I want it to look like right next to the input field]

Here is a picture of what it looks like right now and below it is what I hoped it would look like after applying the css

Comment: Try adding   .group { display: flex; justify-content: space-around; align-items: center; margin-bottom: 10px; flex-wrap: nowrap; }

Comment: As you've used `display: flex`. Then `passowrdError` will come next to `input` by default because the default direction of flexbox is `row`.

Comment: see https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-architecture-nkpqk?file=/src/Form.js

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the suggestions. All of them worked lol because I apparently mistyped infotext into the paragraph's class name which made it not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used tags instead of classes, just replace them with your classnames

```css
div {
  position: absolute
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div className='group'>
  <label>Password</label>
  <input name="password" type="password" value={ this.state.password} onChange={ this.handleChange} />
  <p>{this.state.passwordError}</p>
  <p className='group'>{this.state.passwordError2}</p>
</div><br></br>
```